# The problem with empty cells in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis

With data of size N = 550, I have run multivariate logistic regression in order to regress dichotomous variable of woman postnatal depression (yes/no) on 9 predictors, namely:

- Area of residence: a categorical variable containing 13 areas, the frequency of each ranges from 7 (lowest) to 166.
- Using antibiotic (yes/no)
- Physical activity level: 3 ordinal levels (none, moderate, high)
- Visiting gym level (no gym, sometimes, frequently)
- Receiving aid in taking care of the baby (from mother, maid, etc.): no aid, sometimes, constant aid
- Having physical activity area at home (yes/no)
- last birth difficulty level (5-point scale)
- income level: 9 ordinal categories with frequencies ranging from 13 to 134
- baby age (days): a continuous variable

I ran forward method of selection (conditional), and the remaining at the last step are shown in the picture below:
[image]
The results show big SE's (could even have a size that is one third or one half of the predicted B).

The constant terms is so large, and its exponential value is around 6! this means that much of the model rely on the constant! and the constant was significant too.

I then tried to reduce the size of family income and last birth difficulty by dichotomizing them and the results are not much better. See picture below:

[image]

the VIF statistics for the 9 variables are shown in the picture below:
[image]

the empty cells problem .. this problem i verified using cross-tabs, where i draw a multi-dimensional cross-tab for all the predictors, and i realized so many 0-cells and many "<5" cells.

and for the eigenvalues and its collinearity statistics, actually it was a big table to show here. But I have made it for variables remaining in the last step of the forward method,, and here is the picture:

[image]

Are there other solutions?

Comment: We could guess, but providing a more detailed description of how your independent variables are interrelated would be most helpful.  This likely has nothing to do with logistic regression and everything to do with near-collinearity of the predictors.  The nature of any solutions must depend on what options you have available for obtaining new data and selecting values of the predictors.  Perhaps you could discuss these in an edit to your question.

Comment: predictors had no significant co-linearity. I checked it.

Comment: We need a more detailed description of what's going on: having us guess, and you tell us the guesses don't work, isn't a productive use of anyone's time.

Comment: Please don't repost the same question.  Visit our [help] to learn how this site works.  What are the "empty cells" to which your title refers?

Comment: ok i put some details

Comment: That was great! The collinearity diagnostics are precisely what you need. You have a mildly high condition index of 16. The last two indexes (11 and 16) clearly identify the problem as a combination of (a) little variation in `LastB_diff` (near collinearity with the constant term) and (b) near-collinearity of `PA` and `Gym`, with perhaps `LastB_diff` also involved. You can study the details of these relationships, then, by regressing (using least squares) `LastB_diff` and `Gym` against the five other variables. But most of your question just misinterprets the logistic regression results.